# Can out of memory errors be detected for glTexImage?

Tags: c, opengl

Since, for example, [glBufferData](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferData.xml) can report an GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error, I expected [glTexImage](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) to do so to, but it doesn't.

Presumably it *is* possible to run out of texture memory, so how do I detect the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any OpenGL function can theoretically result in a `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error, if as a side effect of some process, memory needs to be allocated but cannot. As stated by GL 4.4 core profile, section 2.3:

> The Specification attempts to explicitly describe these implicit error conditions (with the exception of OUT_OF_MEMORY) wherever they apply

So the error descriptions don't have to say that `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` can happen. It always can. Though it is odd that they're inconsistent about it, specifically calling out the possibility in certain cases but not others.